# PySpark SQL: difference between query with SQL API or direct embedding

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

Let us consider the PySpark SQL module.
I'd like to know if there is a difference, in terms of performance or other potential indicators, between running a query through the SQL-like API and by embedding SQL clauses directly.

A typical example, with a SELECT query, would be

```
df.where(df.col == 'value')
```

as opposed to

```
sqlc.sql(SELECT * FROM df WHERE col='value')
```

where sqlc is the SQLContext in PySPark.

If there are no differences, where does the possibility to use both syntaxes come from?

Comment: With the first you don't have to write SQL (although of course you need to know it)

Comment: You could use [**`timeit`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to profile the difference.

Comment: `.explain()` will show you that it is exactly the same.